# Modify mapping route depending on spring active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to have a different mapping route of my controller for develop and production environments. I have tried this with `@ConditionalOnExpression`, but it seems that it removes the `@RequestMapping` annotation as well if the condition is false:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/dev")
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'DEV'}")
public class CheckoutController {
```

I would like to add the prefix "/dev" to all mapping routes if the active profile is DEV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create 2 different controllers. Each one for own profile

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/dev")
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'DEV'}")
public class DevCheckoutController {
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/prod")
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[0] == 'PROD'}")
public class ProdCheckoutController {
```

Another (more complicated) way is to override `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. You need the method.

```
    protected RequestMappingInfo createRequestMappingInfo(
        RequestMapping requestMapping, RequestCondition<?> customCondition) {

    return RequestMappingInfo
            .paths(resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(requestMapping.path()))
            .methods(requestMapping.method())
            .params(requestMapping.params())
            .headers(requestMapping.headers())
            .consumes(requestMapping.consumes())
            .produces(requestMapping.produces())
            .mappingName(requestMapping.name())
            .customCondition(customCondition)
            .options(this.config)
            .build();
}
```

In the `.paths(resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(requestMapping.path()))` just add a value depending on profile. So you add environment

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

and the method should be like this

```
String prefix = "DEV".equals(env.getActiveProfiles()[0]) ? "DEV" : ""
return RequestMappingInfo
            .paths(prefix + resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(requestMapping.path()))
```

One more way is to add just an expression to your mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/${my.profile.property:}prod")
```

and for DEV profile just define the property

```
my.profile.property=DEV
```

Comment: note that `resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(requestMapping.path())` returns an array, so we should access the first item to add the prefix: 
`.paths(prefix + resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(requestMapping.path())[0])`
Thanks!

Comment: I would say we should add prefix to all items in the array. If there are multiple mappings pointing the same controller method we should adapt all the mappins.